# How MAP-API works in ANDROID for a simple use case

Tags: android, google-maps

### I wanted to ask some information regarding MAP-API, I am a newbie to MAP-API

---

**How to use a MAP-API**

1. I ran a sample code --- I followed all the procedures on getting the
   key .. etc
2. I could see the executed code that displays a map

---

***But I need to understand one basic concept***

- Suppose i have a list of names of the city stored in a database
- The database is in a external server - (Amazon.server)
- Now i need to show the city names pointed out in my google-map in my
  APP

**What logic should i need to implement. I mean how whole thing works**

*Any Ideas*

***Does SQL-Lite play a role here ?***

**Or**

***Its just one of the solutions ?***

---

**Please go easy on with answers .... I am a newbie**

Comment: Do you mean that you have list of cities and you want to show marker on each city?

Comment: Yes ... Exactly!.... Any materials online for new bie's to help me learn this concept also will be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably follow following steps

1) Query your database to get list of cities

2) get latitude/longitude for each city

here is sample code to do so

```
  String location=cityName;
String inputLine = "";
String result = ""
location=location.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
String myUrl="http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+location+"&output=csv";
try{
 URL url=new URL(myUrl);
 URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  result=inputLine;
  }
  String lat = result.substring(6, result.lastIndexOf(","));
  String longi = result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

3) Now you have latitude longitude for each city and you can show these markers on map
[here is link for details on markers](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)

please comment below if you need more info. :)

cheers!!

Comment: So i need to query my database which is a Amazon server .... but is there a need to use SQL-LIte agin in android client after getting the information from server.... say i get the information of cities as JSON response... do i need to store the results of JSON .. in sql-lite again and then feed it to map API ... or can i direcly map JSON response to MAP API ?

Comment: there is no need to save json response in any sqlite database, you can use data/info directly

Comment: Thanks ... i will give it a try .. and comment back on this link